# Where or what are the instructions for installing FMOD Ex for Linux to use in g++?

Tags: sound, g++

I'm looking for the instructions on how to install FMOD.

I want to do extra credit for my computer graphics assignment - sound effects. A teammate wants me to go with something simple, and he suggested that I use FMOD Ex. (If you guys can think of something better, do suggest it, but so far FMOD looks more promising compared to SDL, OpenAL, etc.)

Right now I'm having a really hard time finding the instructions for installing the latest version of FMOD (audio content creation tool) on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32-bit) so that I can use it in g++ with OpenGL. I checked out this YouTube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avGxNkiAS9g, but it's for Windows. Then, there is a Ubuntu Forums thread which redirected me to this page: https://wiki.debian.org/FMOD, and it has some dated instructions. I've downloaded FMOD Ex v. 4.44.24, which I believe is the latest version. Now I'm looking at eight files:

libfmodex.so;
libfmodex64.so;
libfmodex64-4.44.24.so;
libfmodex-4.44.24.so;

libfmodexL.so;
libfmodexL64.so;
libfmodexL64-4.44.24.so;
libfmodexL-4.44.24.so

... not knowing what to do. I've looked everywhere I could think of: StackOverflow, here, YouTube, Google, ... and came up with zilch.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thank you to Nikos C. on StackOverflow and to chaskes on Ubuntu Forums.

This have helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738213/where-or-what-are-the-instructions-for-installing-fmod-ex-for-linux-to-use-in-g

I guess that all I really had to do was to type in the following in the terminal:

```
cd /usr/local/include/
sudo mkdir fmodex
sudo cp ~/fmodapi44424linux/api/lib/* /usr/local/lib/
sudo cp ~/fmodapi44424linux/api/inc/* /usr/local/include/fmodex
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already unpacked the .tar.gz file, so look in the Documentation directory.

The document `Getting started with FMOD for Linux.pdf` says:

**Installation**

Link the following library into your project:

- Use `api/lib/libfmodex.so` to use the FMOD Ex API.

Comment: Would you recommend using `export` in `.bashrc` or just copy that file to `/usr/local/lib` ?

Comment: There's no one way to do this. `/usr/local/lib/fmodex/api...` is good or `/usr/local/share/fmodex/api...`. You may still need to use `.bashrc` to export it to `PATH`

Comment: Little research has shown that using LD_LIBRARY is not recommended, but do you think that `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` should be enough?

Comment: Yes, that works fine but then you can also just put the api... in your home. I've read to that sometimes it's simpler to just put -I and -L options hard-coded into a project makefile template. But this is all personal preference stuff.  [here's a good explanation](http://wiredrevolution.com/system-administration/how-to-correctly-use-ld_library_path) of ld_library_path...btw, we shouldn't get into chat or new questions in comments.  also, if this solved your install prob, please mark as accepted ;)